# What language features from Objective-C does Swift lack?

Tags: objective-c, swift

From what I understand, Swift does not "natively" support Objective-C [message passing](http://www.buckleyisms.com/home/2014/6/16/the-case-for-message-passing-in-swift.html) - classes that inherit from Obj-C classes can use it, but Swift code use C++ style vtables. That's a major difference between the two languages, and a source for many debates.

Are there any other features of Objective-C that are no longer supported by the current version of Swift (3)?

Comment: What does this have to do with the language smalltalk?

Comment: Objective-C is descended from Smalltalk, while Swift's method of function calls more resembles C++.

Comment: "Descended from" and "resembles" is not close enough, just tag the languages the question actually is about.

Comment: KVO/KVC/bindings, and pretty much anything dynamic.

Comment: Of course Swift "natively" support Objective C message passing. Annotating classes as `@objc` or inheriting from Objective C classes are both natively supported. There's nothing "non-native" about it.

Comment: @Alexander "Non-default" support, then.

Comment: @ApopheniaOverload A distinction so trivial it's not even worth mentioning.

Comment: @Alexander And yet--

https://www.infoq.com/articles/swift-objc-runtime-programming
https://medium.com/@danieltiger/dynamism-and-the-future-of-swift-6777bacab223#.js4cosk26
http://daringfireball.net/linked/2016/05/24/on-dynamism
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11748010
http://mjtsai.com/blog/tag/message-passing/

Comment: @ApopheniaOverload I'm not sure what you're point is. People (myself included) want a dedicated runtime/reflection system for Swift. But that's completely irrelevant on the subject of the false statement "Swift does not "natively" support Objective-C message passing"

Answer (score 1):

## Class Clusters

Swift initializers are a dedicated language feature, that combine Objective C's `alloc` and `init` into one. In Objective C, initializers are just instance methods (called on the allocated, but not initialized, instance created by `alloc`) that follow a particular convention (with regard to their name and function).

The Objective C approach to initializers makes it really easy to create class clusters. That is, to have one abstract superclass that decide for itself the most suitable subclass to initialize.

Consider the case of a general `Image` abstract class, which can either be `PNGImage` or `JPGImage`. You may want to initialize a new `Image` from a path, but you would conventionally have to manually check the type, switch on it, and pick the most suitable subclass to use. Objective C lets you encapsulate this logic in the initializer of `Image`, like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Image: NSObject
@end
  
@interface PNGImage: Image
@end
  
@implementation PNGImage
@end
  
@interface JPGImage: Image
@end
  
@implementation JPGImage
@end
  
@implementation Image
  
  
  
- (id) initFromPath: (NSString *) path {
    NSString *ext = [path pathExtension];

    if ([ext isEqual: @"png"]) return self = [PNGImage init];
    else if ([ext isEqual: @"jpg"]) return self = [JPGImage init];
    else return nil;
}
@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[Image alloc] initFromPath: @"foo.png"]);
}
```

This is done extensively in frameworks like `Foundation`, `AppKit` for classes like `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSImageRep`, and many others.

The Swift alternative is quite simple: just create a class method rather than an initializer:

```
import Foundation

class Image {
    static func from(path: String) -> Image {
        let ext = (path as NSString).pathExtension 
        switch ext {
            case "png": return PNGImage()
            case "jpg": return JPGImage()
            default: fatalError("Unsupported extension: \(ext)")
        }
        return PNGImage()
    }
}

class PNGImage: Image {}
class JPGImage: Image {}

print(Image.from(path: "foo.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Missing C Interoperability Features

### Incomplete Union Support

Swift cannot access the members of a C union. Swift's powerful enumerations take on the role of both C enums and tagged unions, but they're not automatically generated from C unions.